# How to endorse a transaction by 2 organisations using Fabric Gateway in latest version of fabric

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a project in Hyperledger Fabric. I am trying to endorse a transaction by 2 ( and maybe more later ) organisations. I have updated the Application Policies from configtx.yaml file with the following policy for endorsement:

```
Endorsement:      
    Type: Signature     
    Rule: "OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member', 'Org4MSP.member')"
```

I have tried to use fabric gateway in a NodeJS with the following code to create a client and create an asset.

```
async function main(): Promise\<void\> {
    const gateway = connect({
         client,
         identity: await newIdentity(),
         signer: await newSigner(),
         // Default timeouts for different gRPC calls
         evaluateOptions: () =\> {
         return { deadline: Date.now() + 5000 }; // 5 seconds
     },
     endorseOptions: () =\> {
         return { deadline: Date.now() + 15000 }; // 15 seconds
     },
     submitOptions: () =\> {
         return { deadline: Date.now() + 5000 }; // 5 seconds
     },
     commitStatusOptions: () =\> {
         return { deadline: Date.now() + 60000 }; // 1 minute
     },
   });

   try {
      const expirationDate = "12-12-2022";
    
      const transaction = await contract.submitTransaction(
             "CreateAsset",
             expirationDate
       );
   } catch( error ) {
          console.log(error);
   }
}

async function newIdentity(): Promise\<Identity\> {
    const credentials = await fs.readFile(certPath);
    return { mspId, credentials };
}

async function newSigner(): Promise\<Signer\> {
    const files = await fs.readdir(keyDirectoryPath);
    const keyPath = path.resolve(keyDirectoryPath, files\[0\]);
    const privateKeyPem = await fs.readFile(keyPath);
    const privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey(privateKeyPem);

    return signers.newPrivateKeySigner(privateKey);
}
```

The problem is that this transaction will fail, because the gateway only has 1 client which is ORG1, and I also need a transaction from ORG2. Also, how can I restrict which organisations can endorse this transaction? I know I can do it from the chaincode using if statements to check the organisations, but is there something better than if statements in chaincode? Maybe a endorsement request?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway peer should gather all the required endorsements on your behalf.  What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Hello. I have modified in the meantime the name of the organisations. 

NodeJS ERROR: https://pastebin.com/qmjcurCm
Docker Logs : https://pastebin.com/QYumu890

I know that the gateway peer should gather all the endorsements, but how can I sign the transaction by 2 organisations ( or more ) when it is made ?

Comment: It looks like the smart contract deployed to different organisations is behaving differently. They are reading/writing different ledger keys. All your smart contracts are interacting with a single shared ledger so must behave consistently. The log details the differences in behaviour.

Comment: @bestbeforetoday what could be the problem? I mean I have deployed the chaincode as the documentations says and I assume this will be the same chaincode on all the organisations. To mention, this gateway has only one client, which is from Manufacturer Organisation and using that client I made the transaction.